# what is mean kms:encrypt in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-kms

#### I think kms:encrypt is the permission required for encryption. but that's not working

#### So i tested on s3. The results are as below

- S3 is encrypted with kms
- I tested it with IAM user and lambda(role) to upload the file

As a result, both user and lambda required kms:GenerateDataKey permission.

I thought I needed kms:encrypt permission here, but why do I need GenerateKey permission?

#### test-permission

It doesn't work - KMS Key Policy

```
{
            ...

            "Action": [
                "kms:Encrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
```

It works - KMS Key Policy

```
{
            ...

            "Action": [
                "kms:GenerateDataKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
```

Lambda Test Code

```
response = client.put_object(
    Body='filetoupload',
    Bucket='kms-key-test',
    Key=file_name,
)
```

ps. i saw in the aws docs that GenerateDatakey is used for files larger than 4kb. so, i tested with files no larger than 4kb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `kms:GenerateDataKey` permissions because S3 uses [Envelope Encryption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/concepts.html#enveloping). From the [AWS S3 Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingKMSEncryption.html#aws-managed-customer-managed-keys):

> When you use server-side encryption with AWS KMS (SSE-KMS), you can use the default AWS managed key, or you can specify a customer managed key that you have already created. AWS KMS supports envelope encryption. S3 uses the AWS KMS features for envelope encryption to further protect your data. Envelope encryption is the practice of encrypting your plaintext data with a data key, and then encrypting that data key with a KMS key.

Comment: Thank you :)

summarize, When uploading files to s3, use kms:GenerateDataKey.
Because s3 is using envelope encryption.